# how to get value from selected (checkbox) listview and uplaod to server jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, jquery-mobile-listview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd1g1.png)

I just want to upload particular selected value (checked) in listview on server.
There are any values in list with checkbox so I want to select few of them and wants to upload to server.
//below code using to set chekcbox on listview

```
var ajax = {  
        parseJSON:function(result){  
            movieInfo.result = result.entries;
            $.each(result.entries, function(i, row) {
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(row));

                $('#movie-list').append('<li>'+'<h3>' +'Store Name  : '+ row.STORE_NAME + '</h3><p9>' +'Store Id : '+ row.STORE_ID + '</p9> <p2><br>Store Visit Date : '+ row.STORE_VISIT_DATE + '</p2><p2><br>Comment: '+ row.COMMENTS + '</p2><p>' +'Store Issue : '+ row.ISSUE + '</p><p>'+'User : '+ row.USER_NAME + '</li>');
            });

            $('#movie-list').listview('refresh');
        }
    }
```

/// below script i use to upload data to server
// So I just want to get selected valu from ui and uplaod

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uploadbutton").click(function () {
        var S_NO = $("#crm_serialnumber").val();

        var USER_NAME = localStorage.getItem("PMUsername");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",

            url: "https://c.jsp",

           /* url: "https://d="+filename + "&store_name=" + filename2+ "&ph_no="+filename3,*/
            data: {

                "S_NO" : S_NO,

                "USER_NAME" : USER_NAME
            },
            /*
            data: "store_id ="+ filename + "&store_name =" +filename2 + "&ph_no =" + filename3 ,
            */
            success: function (msg,String,jqXHR) {
                window.location='home.html';

                $("#result").html(msg,String,jqXHR)
               alert("Data Uploaded: ");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

//Please help me to solve this problem as I am learning .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you populate your list, i believe you should assign an identifier to your list items, so you can get it later, when you need to post the selection back.

To do that, you can simply set your own custom data-attribute to each list item, the same way you are assigning the text and captions to your paragraphs and headings.

After that, you can filter the checked checkboxes and retrieve the list item which are belonging to:

```js
function getChecked() {
  $("#movie-list :checkbox:checked").each(function(index) {
    // retrieve the list item
    var listItem = $(this).closest("li");
    // get the data associated
    var identifier = listItem.data("identifier");
    var storeName = listItem.data("store-name");
    console.log(index, identifier, storeName);
  });
}
```

```css
#movie-list > li{
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#movie-list .ui-checkbox {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

#movie-list .ui-checkbox .ui-btn {
  border-width: 0 !important;
  border-radius: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page-list" data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <button class="ui-btn ui-mini" onclick="getChecked()">Get checked items</button>
      <br>
      <ul id="movie-list" data-role="listview">
        <li data-identifier="1" data-store-name="store-1">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" />
          <label for="checkbox-1">
            <h2>Stephen Weber</h2>
            <p><strong>You've been invited to a meeting at Filament Group in Boston, MA</strong></p>
            <p>Hey Stephen, if you're available at 10am tomorrow, we've got a meeting with the jQuery team.</p>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li data-identifier="2" data-store-name="store-2">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" />
          <label for="checkbox-2">
            <h2>jQuery Team</h2>
            <p><strong>Boston Conference Planning</strong></p>
            <p>In preparation for the upcoming conference in Boston, we need to start gathering a list of sponsors and speakers.</p>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li data-identifier="3" data-store-name="store-3">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-3" id="checkbox-3" />
          <label for="checkbox-3">
            <h2>Avery Walker</h2>
            <p><strong>Re: Dinner Tonight</strong></p>
            <p>Sure, let's plan on meeting at Highland Kitchen at 8:00 tonight. Can't wait!</p>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply

Comment: //here ams displaying data from json home page
 <div class="example-wrapper" data-iscroll>
            
            <ul data-role="listview" data-insert="true" data-filter="true"  data-filtertext="true" data-role="controlgroup" data-enhanced="true" data- data-input="#search-mini" id="movie-list" data-theme="a"  >
                
                
            </ul>
        </div>

and click of particular list item am sending belonging data to next list

Comment: // below code where i wanted to use checkbox and get the particular data for uplaod

<div data-role="page" id="headline">
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
        <a href="#home" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>                        
        <h3>
            Doctor Info
        </h3>
    </div>        
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview"  id="movie-data" data-theme="a">
              </ul>
    </div>

    
    <input type="button" id="uplaod" value ="Update"  data-theme="b"/>
</div>

Comment: @Gaurav; please don't post code in comments, as it is hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: sir what am trying is just populating json value on lisview that is dynamic ,so how can i give identifier id?? Its not fixed so

Comment: Only you can say which are the fields that are building the primary key of your data. Maybe it is serialnumber, maybe a combination of id's, sadly i haven't a magical crystal ball here right now.

Comment: sir ,there is only one listview id id="movie-data". I where am populating many data in list and out of them i am selecting few nd trying to upload.

Comment: how can I give hard cord id for many some times data is few in list sometimes more. it depends on the jsonn value from backend

Comment: please chek my seocnd question where i have wrote clear thing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768269/get-checked-data-from-dynamic-listview-and-uplaod-to-server